# Latex 'lstlisting' environments ending with unwanted ":" (colon) symbols -- how to get rid of them?

Tags: listings, subfig

I am using `lstlisting` environments (code provided by the `listings` package) in my PhD Thesis; after each instance of this environment, an unexpected and unwanted ":" symbol appears on a line by itself, as per the attached snapshot.

[image]

I have used the following code to obtain the above in latex:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
plot([alpha, falpha, q = 0.1 .. 3], axesfont = ["Times New Roman", "ARIAL", 12], labels = ['alpha', f('alpha')], title = "Model 3", titlefont = ["Times New Roman", 13])
\end{lstlisting}
```

I am using `\lstset` as follows:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{ 
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},  
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.5},        
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                   
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},   
    deletekeywords={...},            
    %escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          
    extendedchars=true,              
    %frame=single,                     
    keepspaces=true,                 
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},       
    language=Octave,                
    morekeywords={*,...},            
    % numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                   
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, 
    rulecolor=\color{black},         
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,         
    showtabs=false,                  
    stepnumber=2,                    
    stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     
    tabsize=2,                     
    title=\lstname                   
}
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me on how to get rid of this ":" symbol appearing after the end of `lstlisting` environments.

---

Here is a minimal working example that reproduces the issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{ 
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}; should come as last argument
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.5},        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
    captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},    % comment style
    deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
    %escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
    %frame=single,                     % adds a frame around the code
    keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
    language=Octave,                 % the language of the code
    morekeywords={*,...},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
    % numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
    numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
    rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
    showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
    showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
    showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    stepnumber=2,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
    stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     % string literal style
    tabsize=2,                     % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}

\title{Test}
\author{Anonymous}
\date{March 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Codes}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
plot([alpha, falpha, q = 0.1 .. 3], axesfont = ["Times New Roman", "ARIAL", 12], labels = ['alpha', f('alpha')], title = "Model 3", titlefont = ["Times New Roman", 13])

\end{lstlisting} 

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to show the command that gives rise to the screenshot you posted.

Comment: @Mico: Thank you for the suggestion. I updated my question with the piece of latex code.

Comment: With the information you provided so far, I can't reproduce the output you get. Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question.

Comment: Your code fragment still isn't compilable because, among other things, you've provided no information about how you've defined the colors `mymauve`, `mygreen`, and `mygray`.

Comment: @leandriis: Thank you very much for the suggestions.
Here, I've provided a minimal working example. When creating this, I found the answer to this problem.
The package "\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}" has caused the problem. When I replaced it with "\usepackage{subfig}", I got rid of that colon symbol :)

Comment: @Mico: I got this problem solved, but I will include the minimal working example in the question. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @user238010 following the Q&A-model of this site the idea is that you post your solution as an answer to your own question, not as an edit.

Comment: @Marijn: Thank you for the suggestion. I didn't know that as I joined today. I reposted it as an answer to this question. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by replacing `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}` with `\usepackage{subfig}`.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subfig}

\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mymauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{ 
    backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}; should come as last argument
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.5},        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
    breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
    breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
    captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},    % comment style
    deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
    %escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
    extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
    %frame=single,                     % adds a frame around the code
    keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},       % keyword style
    language=Octave,                 % the language of the code
    morekeywords={*,...},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
    % numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
    numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{mygray}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
    rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
    showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
    showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
    showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
    stepnumber=2,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
    stringstyle=\color{mymauve},     % string literal style
    tabsize=2,                     % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
    title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}

\title{Test}
\author{Anonymous}
\date{March 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Codes}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
plot([alpha, falpha, q = 0.1 .. 3], axesfont = ["Times New Roman", "ARIAL", 12], labels = ['alpha', f('alpha')], title = "Model 3", titlefont = ["Times New Roman", 13])

\end{lstlisting} 

\end{document}
```